# How do I take each element off of a list and push it onto a stack?

Tags: c#, list, stack, push

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Palindromes\palindromes.txt";

List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
var meStack = new Stack<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    string pali;
    pali = lines.RemoveAt(i);
    meStack.Push(pali[i]);
}
```

Basically I need to `Remove` each element (in the txt there are `40` lines) from the `list` and then `Push` **each** one onto a `stack`.

Comment: Hello, Marvin! Would you please consider formatting the code snippet a bit better?

Comment: The problem is that you are iterating from the start to the end and removing items. So the first iteration you will remove index 0. On the next iteration a new item will be at position zero, and this will be skipped since i is now 1. One way to handle cases like this is to start at the back and iterate towards the start. Then it does not matter if items are removed since they will always have a higher index.

Answer (score 5):

Why even make a list `List<String>`? `ReadAllLines` responds with a `String[]`.  And Stack takes an array as constructor parameter...  So, would code below do the job for you?

```
  string filePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Palindromes\palindromes.txt";
  var meStack = new Stack<string>(File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
```

Comment: Excellent! For reference: [Stack<T>(IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Stack_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__)

Answer (score 3):

Do not `RemoveAt` but `Clear` (if necessary) the `lines` list at the *very end*:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; ++i)
    meStack.Push(lines[i]);

  lines.Clear();
```

Or even (we can get rid of list at all):

```
  string filePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Palindromes\palindromes.txt";

  var meStack = new Stack<string>(); 

  foreach (var item in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    meStack.Push(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it to

```
lines.ForEach(meStack.Push);
lines.Clear();
```

Comment: For Reference: [List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Fildor , sorry forgot to add this & should've  add this , thanks

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. I like to add reference links to my answers. Kind of made it a habit. Feel free to add it into your answer. I found especially new users sometimes aren't even aware, these docs are available.

Answer (score 2):

Your code with some comments:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Palindromes\palindromes.txt";
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
var meStack = new Stack<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
   string pali;
   pali = lines.RemoveAt(i); // < this will return AND REMOVE the line from the list.
                             // now, what was line i+1 is now line i, next iteration
                             // will return and remove (the new) line i+1, though,
                             // skipping one line.
   meStack.Push(pali[i]);    // here you push one char (the ith) of the string (the line you  
                             // just removed) to the stack which _may_ cause an 
                             // IndexOutOfBounds! (if "i" >= pali.Length )
}
```

Now since I do not want to reiterate the other (great) answers, here is one where you can actually use `RemoveAt`:

```
while( lines.Count > 0 ) // RemoveAt will decrease Count with each iteration
{
    meStack.Push(lines.RemoveAt(0)); // Push the whole line that is returned.
    // Mind there is hardcoded "0" -> we always remove and push the first
    // item of the list.
}
```

**Which is not the best solution**, just another alternative.